# C# Best way to transfer Serialized Protobuff data thru http

Tags: c#, .net, protobuf-net, data-transfer-objects

I am using Marc Gravell's [Protobub-Net](https://github.com/mgravell/protobuf-net) to serialize and deserialize objects.

I am looking for the most efficient way to transfer data through an `http://` request.

Here what I have done so far:

```
public string ProtobuffToString()
{
    Dictionary<int, decimal> List1 = new Dictionary<int, decimal>();
    List1.Add(2018, 1.2m);
    List1.Add(2017, 1.4m);
    List1.Add(2016, 1.9m);

    using (var stream = new MemoryStream())
    {
         ProtoBuf.Serializer.Serialize(stream, List1);
        return Convert.ToBase64String(stream.ToArray());
    }
}

public async System.Threading.Tasks.Task<string> ReadProtobuffAsync()
{
    using (System.Net.Http.HttpClient client = new System.Net.Http.HttpClient())
    using (System.Net.Http.HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync("http://localhost:53204/ProtobuffToString")) //<= Will call ProtobuffToString() above
    using (System.Net.Http.HttpContent content = response.Content)
    {
        string result = await content.ReadAsStringAsync();
        byte[] resultByte = Convert.FromBase64String(result);

        using (var stream = new MemoryStream(resultByte))
        {
            return JsonConvert.SerializeObject(ProtoBuf.Serializer.Deserialize<Dictionary<int, decimal>>(stream));
        }
    }
}
```

Can I do it better?

And is it better/faster than to transfer it from json/Json.Net?

Maybe yes because the data transfer will be smaller and the serialization/deserialization faster.

Comment: Just write it to response as is, no need to convert it to string.

Comment: Whats the definition of the most efficient ? how are you rating this, what sort of metrics are you using to judge it

Comment: You can write and read binary streams directly to and from the request and response. Base64 encoding is entirely unnecessary.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Can i do it better?

Protobuf is a binary serialization format that is optimized for (de-)serialization and a low-footprint transfer. By converting the data to Base64 you add another conversion layer and increase the footprint of the transmission.

> And is it better/faster than to transfer it from json/Json.Net?

There is no reasonable argument that would support that claim. Reiterating my previous statement, Protobuf is highly optimized, whereas JSON is some sort of trade-off that is not very efficient to serialize, nor very well readable.

Having said that, have a small example, how to send your Protobuf via HTTP

```
HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
using (var stream = new MemoryStream())
{
    // serialize to stream
    ProtoBuf.Serializer.Serialize(stream, List1);
    stream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);

    // send data via HTTP
    StreamContent streamContent = new StreamContent(stream);
    streamContent.Headers.Add("Content-Type", "application/octet-stream");
    var response = client.PostAsync("http://what.ever/api/upload", streamContent);
}
```

If you'd like to receive Protobuf, you could modify your snippet like

```
using (System.Net.Http.HttpClient client = new System.Net.Http.HttpClient())
using (System.Net.Http.HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync("http://localhost:53204/ProtobuffToString")) //<= Will call ProtobuffToString() above
using (System.Net.Http.HttpContent content = response.Content)
using (var memoryStream = new MemoryStream())
{
    await content.CopyToAsync(memoryStream);
    memoryStream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin); // reset stream

    return ProtoBuf.Serializer.Deserialize<Dictionary<int, decimal>>(memoryStream); // assuming that you return the Dictionary, not a string
}
```

Actually I don't see why you wanted to return the `string` instead of the `Dictionary<int, decimal>` from `ReadProtobuffAsync`. I'd recomment to drop the `Dictionary` altogether and use meaningful protobuf definitions and corresponding classes, because this is the really strong point of Protobuf.

Answer (score 3):

The question and answers are subjective based entirely on the definition of "best". I do see a lot of "extra" code that is not necessary. I recommend you work directly with Streams, there is no need to go to memory stream first or convert to base64 or convert to json. If you do need a string representation do it in another utility method instead of wrapping it in this code as well.

Write Code

```
// depending on where you want to write to pass an appropriate Stream like a stream to write directly to an HttpPost or File on disk,
// there is no need to write to memory
public void SerializeToStream(Stream destinationStream)
{
    Dictionary<int, decimal> List1 = new Dictionary<int, decimal>();
    List1.Add(2018, 1.2m);
    List1.Add(2017, 1.4m);
    List1.Add(2016, 1.9m);

    ProtoBuf.Serializer.Serialize(destinationStream, List1);
}
```

Read Code

```
public async System.Threading.Tasks.Task<Dictionary<int, decimal>> ReadProtobuffAsync()
{
    using (System.Net.Http.HttpClient client = new System.Net.Http.HttpClient())
    using (System.IO.Stream responseStream = await client.GetStreamAsync("http://localhost:53204/ProtobuffToString"))
    {
        // deserialize directly from the response stream
        return ProtoBuf.Serializer.Deserialize<Dictionary<int, decimal>>(responseStream));
    }
}
```